# Does every 3CNF propositional formula has an equisatisfiable 2CNF propositional formula

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, propositional-logic

Does every 3CNF propositional formula has an **equisatisfiable** 2CNF propositional formula?

Comment: There are satisfiable 2SAT instances and not. There are satisfiable 3SAT instances and not. I think that validity of formula $\exists f\forall g: 2SAT(f)=3SAT(g)$ is not hard to evaluate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If the 3CNF formula is satisfiable, here is an equisatisfiable 2CNF formula: True.  If the 3CNF formula is not satisfiable, here is an equisatisfiable 2CNF formula: False.  So yes, every 3CNF formula has an equisatisfiable 2CNF formula.

If you want to actually *find* that formula in a reasonable amount of time, then we don't know of any way to find such a formula in polynomial time (existence of such a method would prove that P = NP).

Comment: But what is the proof then?

Comment: @ErezZrihen The above is a perfect proof of the existence of the equisatisfiable 2CNF. It's even a constructive proof. I don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: But somehow it's possible to make a 2SAT with same amount of positive assignments in polynomial time or am I wrong?

Comment: The proof that the answer to my question is positive is by the definition of equisatisfiable, am I right?